# How can i estimate the apparent size of an object?

Tags: astronomy

I would like to be able to estimate, the apparent size of some object. The motivation behind this, is to use the correct numbers, in a sci-fy novel i am writing.

Só, i want to be able to calculate, how big a ship would look like, flying at some altitude, for a human looking at it from the ground.

I found out that the angular diameter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter) could be what i am looking form, but i didn't managed to understand how to use/interpret the formula.

Comment: Here's a [calculator with a diagram](https://rechneronline.de/sehwinkel/angular-diameter.php) that might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered the correct formula for calculating the angle that defines the diameter of an object at a distance from the observer, assuming that you need not account for atmospheric influences. In order to interpret it, you must refer to the diagram.

Perhaps the question that you have is how an observer interprets the actual size of an object based upon the angular diameter. Simply put, it is not possible to find a linear measurement from the angular diameter alone. Consider the situation in which one is observing the moon from the Earth. If one were to hold a ruler up directly in front of the eye, the apparent size of the moon might be a few millimetres. However, if one drew the ruler away from the eye, its linear diameter would appear to grow as the distance of the ruler from the eye increased.

The size of astronomical objects is determined by first calculating the distance of the object from the observer. The most common method to determine the distance to stars is the parallax method. This involves measuring the distance that the object moves in the sky as the Earth, and hence the observer, moves around the sun. Those objects are measured against very distant objects, which do not appear to move because of their great distance. This method is only useful with a knowledge of the width of the axis of orbit relative to the star. Once one knows the angular diameter, semi-axes of orbit of the observer, and the distance to the object, the actual size of the object can be calculated.

For more information on this, I recommend you look at one of the sights which describes the "parallax method".